# Google Firebase push notifications are not sending with image

Tags: php, android, ios, firebase, push-notification

I am working on sending push notifications using Google Firebase in php.

Here is the code for Ios, android & web browsers.

```
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$headers = array('Authorization:key=KEY', 'Content-Type: application/json');

/*--- send notification to IOS devices ---*/
    $ios_array = array("topic" => "/topics/ios_1234");
    $ios_array['url'] = $browser_url;
    $ios_array['image'] = $image;

    $fields = array(
        "to" => "/topics/ios_1234",
        "priority" => "high",
        "notification" => array(
            "title" => "Title",
            "body" => "This is a test message",
            "sound" => "default",
            "content_available" => true),
        "data" => $ios_array);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    /*--- send notification to Android device ---*/
    $android_array = array("title" => "Title", "body" => "This is a test message", "sound" => "default");
    $android_array['url'] = $browser_url;
    $android_array['image'] = $image;
    $fields = array(
        "to" => "/topics/android_1234",
        "priority" => "high",
        "data" => $android_array,
        "content_available" => true);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    /*--- send notification to WEB Browsers ---*/
    $radio_url = "https://example.com";
    $fields = array(
        "to" => "/topics/web_1234",
        "priority" => "high",
        "notification" => array(
            "title" => "Title",
            "body" => "This is a test message",
            "icon" => "",
            "click_action" => $radio_url,
            "image" => $image));

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result == 1) {
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Where $image & $browser_url are image url & redirecting urls respectively.

I am trying to send image in all of the devices but image is not displayed in browser notifications and in ios & android, notification itself is not received when image is included in the notification.

Can someone help me in this?

Comment: Value for the $image variable is empty

Comment: @Umar No the value is there.